# Is there a Preprocessor Option that display when header files are preprocessed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Looking through the MSDN, I would say no; however, I thought I would ask here before I give up.

Is there a preprocessor option for Visual Studios that displays when a header file is included? Specifically, I'm looking for something similar to **/verbose:lib** described in the link below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wdsk6as6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If it's to diagnose a problem, I use /P to send the output to a file - that will include line information so you know what got included when and from where.  /E goes to sdtout but neither can be used for a normal build (no obj will be created).

Comment: You can always use `#warning` to output things like a poor mens printf debugging.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I'm trying to find when files are included and having trouble doing so in conventional ways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The switch `/showIncludes` (List Include Files) is what you are looking for, as documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Here is a sample of the output produced by that switch:

Given the file **main.c**, consisting of:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

and the file **foo.h**, consisting of:

```
#include "bar.h"
```

The output produced is:

```
Note: including file: d:\temp\foo.h
Note: including file:  d:\temp\bar.h
```

Comment: Oh!  Well that's way better than `/P` (Preprocess to a File) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6(v=vs.80).aspx!